# Cannot use Matchers when mocking with Scalamock

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest, scalamock

We are trying to run a test with ScalaMock and ScalaTest using the matcher `should be`. The code is the following:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with Matchers {

  "A turtle" should "say hello!" in {

    val m = mock[Pluto]
    val turtle = new Turtle(m)

    (m.say _).expects(15).returns("ciao 15")

    //assert(turtle.ciao === "ciao 15")
    turtle.ciao should be ("ciao 15")
  }
```

This are our imports in gradle (it's a mixed project java+scala):

```
testCompile 'org.scalamock:scalamock-scalatest-support_2.10:3.0.1',
        'junit:junit:4.11',
        'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:1.42',
        "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:${hamcrestVersion}",
        "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:${hamcrestVersion}",
        "org.jmock:jmock:${jmockVersion}"
testCompile("org.jmock:jmock-junit4:${jmockVersion}") {
    exclude group: "junit"
}
```

The error we are having is:

```
[ant:scalac] /Users/dierre/IdeaProjects/sitecustomizer/src/test/scala/org/eianni/sitecustomizer/ExampleSpec.scala:20: error: not found: type Matchers
[ant:scalac] class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with Matchers {
[ant:scalac]                                                          ^
[ant:scalac] /Users/dierre/IdeaProjects/sitecustomizer/src/test/scala/org/eianni/sitecustomizer/ExampleSpec.scala:30: error: not found: value be
[ant:scalac]     turtle.ciao should be ("ciao 15")
[ant:scalac]                        ^
[ant:scalac] two errors found
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: How are you installing scalatest (sbt? other?), and what version are you on?